# DataStateBehavior - States not firing?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Have this logic in view model:

```
private void ExecuteTestConnectionCommand()
{
    _IsBusy = true;
    _connectionTester.CanConnect(_currentConnectionString);
    _IsBusy = false;
}

public const string IsBusyPropertyName = "IsBusy";    
private bool _IsBusy = false;    
public bool IsBusy
{
    get
    {
        return _IsBusy;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_IsBusy == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        RaisePropertyChanging(IsBusyPropertyName);
        _IsBusy = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(IsBusyPropertyName);
    }
}
```

**CanConnect has blocking operation.**

Want to do some animation on the Test Connection button for fun.  When IsBusy = true, want the button to do fade in and out (or at least some kind of animation).

So far I have:

```
<Button x:Name="buttonTest" Command="{Binding TestConnectionCommand}" Content="Test">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ei:DataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding IsBusy}" 
            Value="True" TrueState="BusyState" FalseState="NotBusyState"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

and states:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:3" To="BusyState">
                <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                    <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
            </VisualTransition>
            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:4" To="NotBusyState">
                <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                    <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
            </VisualTransition>
            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:2">
                <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                    <BounceEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
            </VisualTransition>
        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualState x:Name="BusyState">
            <Storyboard AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="NotBusyState"/>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

When I click the test button, no animation happens as far as I can tell. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure as this may be completely off but is your property 'IsBusy' not getting captured by looking at the private equivalent '_IsBusy'?  It looks like your model is following the MVVM structure of having a private property then be set following the pattern:

```
private string _Thing;

Public string Thing
{
    get { return _Thing; }
    set { _Thing = value; }
   RaisePropertyChanged("Thing")
}
```

Traditionally Raise Property is implemented most times in a base viewmodel by inheriting the 'INotifyPropertyChanged' Interface and implementing similar logic to this:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Generally you pass in the string name of your property and then the system knows to expose the change to it to view.

I know in my cases with doing things with MVVM and something does not get raised it is usually that I need to implement 'RaisePropertyChanged' effectively or try calling the PUBLIC PROPERTY check instead of the private when the XAML is making the changes.

Comment: hmm tried what you said and also posted the entire property.  Still nothing happens.

Comment: Unless you are implementing ways I have not seen yet you are doing RaisePropertyChanged's implementation is wrong.  Generally you put the string 'name' of the property in double quotes and it uses reflection to raise the property notification.  Updated my answer for further explanation.

Comment: Your constant string may be okay at further looking.  I would try to set breakpoints under your 'set' operation and ensure that changes to your view are actually being raised effectively.